# Why is my sine wave frequency sweep not correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, wav, waveform

I'm trying to create a simple WAV file that emits a changing pitch. However, the waveform that gets written to the file does not correspond to the data that `get_sample` returns.

I expect the tone to change in a logarithmic fashion, starting at A10 (28,160 Hz) and to end at A0 (27.5 Hz). As each second passes, the pitch should smoothly drop by one octave.

What is actually happening is difficult to explain. The tone changes, but in unintended ways. And what makes my problem more peculiar is that lowering the sample rate worsens the problem. In [this output](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0Ng7sKR0CmN) at 48,000 samples per second, the pitch rapidly drops and then rises again just to slowly fall once more. In [this output](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0TOHGcXegNG) at 3,000 samples per second, a similar effect happens, but it is more extreme and chaotic. What am I doing wrongly?

```
from math import pi, sin
from sys import byteorder
import wave

def get_sample(time):
    frequency = a10 / 2.0 ** time
    # print('{:.15f} {:.15f} {:.15f}'.format(time, frequency, sin(pi2 * frequency * time)))
    return sin(pi2 * frequency * time)

pi2 = 2 * pi
a10 = 28160.0

NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS = 1
SAMPLE_RATE = 48000  # samples per second
SAMPLE_WIDTH = 3  # bytes
DURATION = 10  # seconds

MAX_SAMPLE_VALUE = 2 ** (SAMPLE_WIDTH * 8 - 1)

samples = bytearray()

for i in range(SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION):
    time = i / SAMPLE_RATE
    sample = round(get_sample(time) * MAX_SAMPLE_VALUE)

    if sample == MAX_SAMPLE_VALUE:
        sample -= 1

    samples.extend(sample.to_bytes(SAMPLE_WIDTH, byteorder, signed=True))

with wave.open('output.wav', 'wb') as output:
    output.setnchannels(NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS)
    output.setsampwidth(SAMPLE_WIDTH)
    output.setframerate(SAMPLE_RATE)
    output.setnframes(NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS * SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION)
    output.setcomptype('NONE', 'not compressed')

    output.writeframes(samples)
```

Comment: @mkrieger1, see the edit.

Answer (score 2):

A Frequency of 28,160Hz is to high for a sample rate of 48000.

And a sample rate of 3,000Hz , the maximum frequency would be less than 1.5KHz

This is related to the Nyquist sample rate.  In short the maximum frequency you can sample at a given sample rate is 1/2 the Sample rate.  In reality it is less than 1/2 the sample rate.

Please See:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency
```

0 https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Given a 48000Hz sample rate, the maximum frequency you can sample is 24,000Hz.  This maximum frequency is IDEALIZED , it would be much less.

To capture 28,160Hz frequency, you will need a sample rate more than 56,320Hz. Say 64,000Hz, or better yet 
96000Hz sample rate.

**EDIT:  BTW**  <strike>Why is  frequency function raising to the power of TIME ? **</strike>

That would cause some weird aliasing effects

I believe it should be Should be:

```
frequency = a10 * time
```

I see... you're doing a frequency Sweep. thus adjusting the Frequency at each sample time.

Comment: And once you succeed in generating a pure tone at 28,160 Hz you won't be able to hear it :-)

Comment: Even after changing the starting frequency to A7 (3,520 Hz) and the duration to seven seconds, I get the same effect when keeping the sample rate of 48,000 Hz. A "bounce" seems to always occur at around 1.44 s.

Comment: The "Bounce" you hear is called an ALIAS Effect. Iit is what happens when your sample rate is too slow for the given frequency. Under-Sampled.

Comment: How is a sample rate of 48,000 Hz insufficient for a tone of at most 3,520 Hz though? That's nearly fourteen samples per period. That's obviously not ideal, but it's enough to convey the tone (poorly albeit). If I change the `get_sample` function to emit a constant tone, everything works fine; the pitch is spot on. :/

Comment: I'm having a bit of an issue about how you limit your SWEEP to be between the start and end frequency?

Comment: I'm sure that you see that the frequency is `a10 / 2.0 ** time`. `a10` is of course just a constant. So when `time == 0.0`, the frequency will be `a10 / 2.0 ** 0.0 == a10 / 1.0 == a10`. This matches exactly what I expect. Letting `time = 1.0`, the frequency ends up being `a10 / 2.0 ** 1.0 == a10 / 2.0 == a9`, as expected. Letting `time = 2.0`, the frequency becomes `a10 / 2.0 ** 2.0 == a10 / 4.0 == a8`, and so forth. I want the solution to my problem to be as simple as a flaw in my logic, but I'm failing to see it.

Comment: I'm working it out.  It was not clear. All the parts are spread out.  You don't  limit it, except by hard coding the ranges based on the start freq and duration.   so.. working it out in my head.  step by step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148263/discussion-between-phillip-williams-and-tyler-crompton).

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.

#### Aliasing

A signal sampled at a rate *f*<sub>S</sub> can only be reconstructed correctly if it contains no components at frequencies higher than *f*<sub>S</sub>/2. Any signal components with frequencies outside the interval [0, *f*<sub>S</sub>/2] get *folded* into that interval when reconstructing the signal from the samples (e.g. by your soundcard).

This is called [*aliasing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions) and can be avoided by either low-pass filtering a signal before sampling it or by making the sampling rate sufficiently high.

In your case, if you want to sample a sine wave with a frequency of 28160 Hz, the sampling rate must be at least 56320 Hz.

#### Incorrect computation of phase

> ```
> def get_sample(time):
>     frequency = a10 / 2.0 ** time
>     return sin(pi2 * frequency * time)
> ```

The *phase* is the argument to the `sin` function. Its derivative with respect to time is the [*instantaneous frequency*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase#Instantaneous_frequency) which is the pitch of the tone we hear.

In this case, if we plug `frequency = a10 / 2.0 ** time` into `pi2 * frequency * time`, the phase is

```
pi2 * (a10 / 2.0 ** time) * time
```

or in symbolic notation:

φ = 2π · A10 · 2<sup>−*t*</sup> · *t*

The [derivative of this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+2+pi+*+A+*+2%5E(-t)+*+t+by+t) is then

*f* = 2π · A10 · 2<sup>−*t*</sup> · (1 − ln 2 · *t*),

and not 2π · A10 · 2<sup>−*t*</sup> as you had expected.

This is a plot of the actual frequency sweep that you get using your method (taking into account aliasing, notice how the curve is reflected at the 0 Hz and 24000 Hz lines), vs. what you had intended:

[image: frequency sweep (linear scale)]

And here is the same plot with logarithmic frequency scale, which is how we perceive frequencies as pitches:

[image: frequency sweep (logarithmic scale)]

#### Solution

You get the correct result by making the following changes:

1. Use a high enough value for `SAMPLE_RATE`.
2. Don't calculate the sample directly from the given time, instead maintain a phase value which is incremented at a rate proportional to the intended frequency (wrap it at 2π so that it doesn't grow out of bounds), by replacing

   > ```
   > def get_sample(time):
   >     frequency = a10 / 2.0 ** time
   >     return sin(pi2 * frequency * time)
   >
   > […]
   >
   > for i in range(SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION):
   >     time = i / SAMPLE_RATE
   >     sample = round(get_sample(time) * MAX_SAMPLE_VALUE)
   > ```

   by

   ```
   def get_frequency(time):
       frequency = a10 / 2.0 ** time
       return frequency

   […]

   phase = 0
   for i in range(SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION):
       time = i / SAMPLE_RATE
       f = get_frequency(time)
       phase = (phase + pi2 * f / SAMPLE_RATE) % pi2
       sample = round(sin(phase) * MAX_SAMPLE_VALUE)
   ```